# Stored Procedure is failing on Azure Logic Apps

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I am developing a logic app which gets the data from the client API and loads it on our UAT DB. In this logic app, I have a stored procedure that I am running using the SQL connection and selecting Execute Stored Procedure. This stored procedure runs perfectly fine for 15-20 times but then it starts failing. If I execute the procedure manually it works perfectly fine on SSMS there are no errors, and the logic app runs only for 30-45 seconds when it errors out. Running the stored procedure in an if condition because we are getting data for two sites. I have checked the connection they are good. I am quite new in developing logic apps, any and all help is appreciated.  [image: Failure and success runs]

Edit: Adding an image of the successful execution of the move procedure.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are passing nothing into stored procedure, see Body parm.  Is that what was intended?  Do all failures look like that and the ones that succeed pass actual data in that parm?

Comment: Hi Scott, the success pass also looks the same. There is nothing on the body.

Comment: Is this stored procedure returning data?  The error message is about invalid json.  Could it be returning a large amount and it is being truncated.  Or maybe the formatting is invalid.  Only guesses I have at this point.

Comment: The way the stored procedure is written is to just copy the data from the staging table to the production table. So it is technically not returning anything back.

Comment: No ideas then., sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer to it. In my situation particularly we had a trigger that would check for on some specific column on the data. That trigger was causing the issue, I disabled the trigger and ran the logic app it is working fine now. No fails on the run.